# How to run multiple for loops in C programming?

Tags: c, for-loop, multiplication, cubic

I am trying to find the cube of the numbers from 1 to 10 using various types of for loops. I was wondering why after my for loop evaluates, the program stops and does not go on to evaluate the while loop? Can someone help? The for loop and while loop are supposed to do the same thing by the way. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(void) 
{
    int num;
    for ( num=1; num<11; num++){
        printf("The cube of %d is %d\n", num, num*num*num);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main1(void)
{
    int num1;
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    while (num1<11) {
        printf("The cube of %d is %d\n", num1, num1*num1*num1);
        num1++;
        }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

PS My first programming language is Python, so I am confused why C stop after the first for loop... 
:(

Comment: Your program will terminate when the special `main()` function returns.  Try having each kind of cubing performed in a helper function. Then have `main` call both of them, one after the other.

Comment: `main()` is the entry point of your program. `main1()` is a function that is never called. If you think of it in terms of python - `main()` and `main1()` would be equal to `def main()` and `def main1()` - how would you call those functions in python?

Comment: In addition, if both mains are in the same file you do not need to include stdio 2x. after the for loop you might try `int resultMain = main1();`

Comment: It wouldn't work for inputs more than 10 anyways because you put `while (num1<11)`. Your loop isn't even entered if `num1` scanned as more than 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main()` and `main1()` are two different functions. Your system calls `main()`, the entry point of your program. When `main()` ends, that is when your program terminates. `main1` isn't touched at all.

Either concatenate the two functions (copy-paste `main1` into `main`) or call `main1()` from `main()`. But you would need a forward-declaration first:

```
int main1(void);

int main(void)
{
    // ...
    main1();
}

int main1(void) { ... }
```

BTW, `main1` isn't a really good name for a function since it resembles `main`. That can confuse people who maintain your code.

Comment: It's bad not only for resembling `main`, but also for lacking any description of what it does. Personally I would choose something like `cubeByFor` and `cubeByWhile` and call each from `main`.

Answer (score -2):

after declaring num and num1 you set num in the for loop to 1, but not num1 in the while loop.    plus the main functions issues mentioned